# Default argument with template in C++

Tags: c++, templates, arguments, default-arguments

I'm designing an interface, by which users can define a class that tells what they want to do.
The code is something like the following,

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Dummy{
public:
    void do(){ printf("do nothing\n"); }
};

class Task{
public:
    void do(){ printf("do something\n"); }
};

template <class TASK>
void func(TASK &task = Dummy()){
    task.do();
}

int main(){
    func(); // do nothing
    Task task;
    func(task); // do something
}
```

How to make it work?

Comment: What's wrong with the code as you have it? (This is important information since that is what future visitors with the same problem should be searching for.)

Comment: Do not edit answers into your question. Answers belong in the answers. You've already indicated which solution worked for you by accepting that answer. (If you want to share the exact version you used, you can answer your own question, but please keep the acceptance of the answer that got you there.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is this `func` argument:

```
TASK &task = Dummy()
```

It will not work unless it is `const`. This happens because non-const lvalue reference to type cannot bind to a temporary.

But if you can use `const` there, you can easily solve your problem:

```
class Dummy{
public:
    void doit() const { printf("do nothing\n"); }
};

class Task{
public:
    void doit() const { printf("do something\n"); }
};

template <class TASK = Dummy>
void func(const TASK &task = TASK()){
    task.doit();
}

int main(){
    func(); // do nothing
    Task task;
    func(task); // do something
}
```

Comment: This will work only for const `TASK::do` member functions. Wouldn't be better to use `void func(TASK&& task = TASK())`, which will work both for lvalue and rvalue arguments and both const and non-const `do` functions?

Comment: @DanielLangr yea, that one should work too, but I normally **never** use this binding. Because it can create strange behavior. Assume that there is `int k=0;` in `Dummy` and `Task`. in that case `task.k++;` is a valid statement in `func`, but does it have any meaning for temporary variable? **No**. So I personally never use it like that.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, don't have an identifier (function named) named `do`, since `do` is a language keyword.   Using it as an identifier is a diagnosable error.   There's no option other than changing the name of the function.

Second, the argument will of `func()` will need to be `const`, since the default value being passed is a temporary (which can only be bound to a `const` reference).   This also means your function in the classes needs to be `const` qualified.

Third, when calling `func()` it is necessary to either pass SOME information so the compiler can work out how to instantiate the template.    If you want to pass no information at all at the call site (i.e. `func()`) then you need to have a non-templated overload.

Fourth, use C++ streams rather than C I/O.

```
 class Dummy
 {
    public:
       void do_it() const { std::cout << "do nothing\n"; }
 };

 class Task
 {
    public:
       void do_it() const { std::cout << "do something\n"; }
 };

 template <class TASK>
  void func(const TASK &task)
  {
     task.do_it();
  }

  void func()
  {
      func(Dummy());
  }

  int main()
  {
     func(); // do nothing
     Task task;
     func(task); // do something
  }
```

Option 2 is to replace the two versions of `func()` above with

```
 template <class TASK = Dummy>
  void func(const TASK &task = TASK())
  {
     task.do_it();
  }
```

Comment: I think first mode is only useful if you really needs non-const argument for `func`. You can remove `const` from argument and write second function like this: `void func { Dummy{}.do_it(); }`.